# Why use Wine application in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wine

Is it really practical to use wine application in Ubuntu? I don't know if I really need wine applications to installed. That's why I need some suggestions from the experts whether to download it or not. I have Ubuntu 12.04 alongside of Windows 7.

Comment: Totally depends on _your_ needs and whether _you_ feel the need to run Windows apps while using Linux.

Comment: why do you have Ubuntu installed? Why do you have Windows installed? It all depends on **your** needs. Close the question, it's not constructive.

Comment: Closing this because it seems to be more rhetorical than a real question, as the previous comments have pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what applications you want to use. Wine is sort of a 'layer' that enables you to run some Microsoft Windows applications on Ubuntu. For a lot of Windows applications, there are native alternatives available in the Ubuntu Software Center. For example, Rhythmbox and Banshee are great native alternatives for iTunes. Gimp is a good alternative for Photoshop.

My advice is to only install Wine if you want to run the Windows applications instead of the native alternatives. The native applications are usually better integrated in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have no need for it and haven't used a Windows app since 2008.

If you find that you have a need for a specific app while inside windows - then perhaps it is for you.

I would say that if you find you're using (or need) a lot of windows apps then you will be better off either finding and working with a linux alternative, a dual-boot and booting that when you need to work in Windows apps.

There is always the alternative in using a virtual machine inside of Ubuntu.

Not all windows apps will work with wine - always good to check at the wine app database - http://appdb.winehq.org/

Answer (score 0):

I need to run the Word, e-sword. Some need MS Office and don't want windows. Some Want their games but wants freedom of Linux. Suppose there is no wine....then what? 
All these precious people will miss freedom and hence become forced to do dual boot.

If you do not need it today it doe not mean you won't need it. Even if you don't need it others do!
With all due respect the question is either un-reasearched or meaningless!